# extracting a sentence using a tokenizer

Tags: java, string, string-comparison, stringtokenizer

There is a simple code that compares two strings and then if it contains a keyword, it will do some action. The thing is that I wish after I detecting the keyword in the text, it somehow extract the sentence that it is within it. Here is the code:

```
String keyword="Keyword(S)";

StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(text) ;

if(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    tokenizer.nextToken();

    for(final String s :text.split(" ")){

        if(keyword.equals(s))
        {
            //get the whole sentence
        } 
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a sample: 
Considering we have the following text:

```
    Text summarization is the process of extracting salient information from the source text and to present that
information to the user in the form of summary. It is very difficult for human beings to manually
summarize large documents of text. Automatic abstractive summarization provides the required solution
but it is a challenging task because it requires deeper analysis of text. In this paper, a survey on abstractive
text summarization methods has been presented. Abstractive summarization methods are classified into two
categories i.e. structured based approach and semantic based approach.
```

now we are looking for the all the sentences that contains the word `abstractive` and then return the sentence. Maybe we should store a token as it reaches to a `.` and then whenever we find the keyword, we use that token to get the beginning of the sentence and continue until we reach another `.` or that sounds unreasonable?

Comment: What is title and what does it contain? Why are you ignoring the words you get from the tokenizer?

Comment: @Eran the tokenizer is just meant to check if we reach at the end of the document and the title is a text version of a`pdf` that is extracted using some libraries

Comment: @Eran there was some typo that made you confused so I edited the code., maybe now it looks more clear or still not?

Comment: if(tokenizer.countTokens()>0){

Comment: @JudeNiroshan it has same function as what I used for `if` condition and solved nothing.

Comment: how about providing possible values for 'text' and for them, expected result?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan the problem is not about the `if` condition but about `contains` method which matches all the other words that starts with the initial of the keyword.

Comment: provide your test case sample.

Comment: @Eran I changed the whole question scope. is this ok to take a look at it now? The question is now that who to get the sentence that keyword is within it.

Comment: @Prashant how about now

Comment: @lonesome : i think your text is containing new line also..

Comment: @Prashant so? my point is that how to get the sentence as soon as we get the keyword in a text like the example? is it possible to use `Stringtokenizer` or need some other techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should create token on the basis of `.` and then check the keyword as below:

```
    String keyword="summarization";
    StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(text,"\\.") ;

     while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
     {
             String x= tokenizer.nextToken();

              for(final String s :x.split(" ")){

               if(keyword.equals(s))
               {
                    System.out.println(x);
               } 
            }
     }
```

Comment: that was nice! i had the idea of considering the `.` as mentioned in the question but didnt know how to do it. there is an improvement. is it possible that using more than one delimiters like `.` and `,` and `;` for a single tokenizer?

Comment: you can use split() method or Pattern and Matcher class.

Comment: you mean in the `for loop`?

Comment: yes there you can pass `regex` StringTokenizer doesn't support regex.

Comment: so the idea is first using `delim` argument to make new sized tokens then using `regex` or first using `regex` and then using `delim`? to my mind since `,` and `;` are usually a subset of a sentence, should first use `delim`? right?

Comment: yes first you need to tokenize on the basis of statement (using .) then you can split it into smaller part using regex.

Comment: ok. will do it sooner or later.